# Remove from a list same links but with different url

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup, duplicates

I have a list with several links which many of them are backup links from others. So the code ends going through the "same page" twice in some cases;for example:

```
['https://EXAMPLE.com/t34-EXAMPLE-965-OPTION-ONE', 'https://EXAMPLE.com/t29-EXAMPLE-964-SINGLE-OPTION', 'https://EXAMPLE.com/t33-EXAMPLE-965-OPTION-TWO', ]
```

How can I remove those second options, or even third sometimes, from the list?

Comment: I didn't understand exactly what you try to achieve here?
can you explain more?

Comment: Do clarify your question a little bit. Are you saying you have some links that have appeared more than once and you'd like to ignore those?

Comment: Sorry about being unclear. What I want to do is to only maintain the primary links; as you can see in the example there's two links containing 965, I want to keep only one of those and remove the other from the list since it's the same page but with a different link. Hope to be clearer this time.

Comment: Is there a constant string(s) that identifies either the links you want or don't want? And how  did you obtain this list?

Comment: Yes, all the EXAMPLE parts in the strings are the same

Comment: But that differentiates the ones you want from the ones you don't want? EXAMPLE is present in both. Are these coming from a website?

Comment: No, after the slash (/) everything except the example variates. And yeah they're from a website

Comment: Is the website public?

Comment: Yes, it's a public website

Answer (score 1):

You can use a set to keep track of what links have been seen, sans options. If links that are different point to the same 'page' you'll need to write a function that can determine which parts of the URL are important and uniquely identify destination pages.

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse
seen = set()
unique_links = []
def identify_link(url):
    """
    Given a URL, give a unique identity for the link
    I.E. remove any options from the url
    "https://EXAMPLE.com/t34-EXAMPLE-965-OPTION-ONE" -> ("t34", "EXAMPLE", "965")
    """
    path = urlparse(url).path
    a, b, c, *options = path.split('-')
    return a,b,c

for link in links:
    identity = identify_link(link)
    if identity in seen:
        continue
    else:
        seen.add(identity)
    unique_links.append(link)
```

You'll have to adjust `identity_link` to suit your needs, as this implementation makes some assumptions about the structure of links that may not hold true in every case.